# error occurs during the project of android studio

Tags: android, json, firebase, dart, yaml

My `pubspec.yaml`:

```
cupertino_icons: "^0.1.2"
          firebase_auth: "^0.15.5+3"
          firebase_core: any
          firebase_database: "^3.1.3"
```

Here is the error:

> /Users/sunny/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color packages get Error
>   detected in pubspec.yaml: Error on line 26, column 7: Expected a key
>   while parsing a block mapping.    ╷ 26 │       cupertino_icons:
>   "^0.1.2"    │       ^    ╵ Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at
>   /Users/sunny/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app1/connect_world/firebase_setup/pubspec.yaml

Process finished with exit code 1:
[image]

Comment: Add whole `pubspec.yaml` file

Answer (score 0):

pubspec.yaml file require a correct usage of identation (using space and no tabs), see here for more info : https://learn.getgrav.org/16/advanced/yaml#yaml-basic-rules

Edit your file with this :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: "^0.1.2"
  firebase_auth: "^0.15.5+3"
  firebase_core: any
  firebase_database: "^3.1.3"
```

Comment: Thanks you sir.. now i'm able to make my app